# Trouble with C program blank output

Tags: c

```
int i=0,j=0;

char string[100], string2[100];
scanf("%s",&string);

while (string[i]!='\0'){
    if(string[i]=='a' || string[i]=='e' || string[i]=='i' || string[i]=='o' || string[i]=='u' || string[i]=='A' || string[i]=='E' || string[i]=='I' || string[i]=='O' || string[i]=='U'){
        string[i]=string2[j];
    }
    string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    string[i] = string2[j];
    string2[j-1]='.';
}
printf("%s", string2);

return 0;
```

The question is entering a word and then removing all vowels, adding '.' after every constant and making all upper case letters lower case.

Comment: The program does not terminate because `i` is nowhere incremented. – What about using a *debugger* to locate your problem?

Comment: ...and `string2[j-1]='.';` on the first save invokes undefined behavior, as `j` is `0` and the resulting index is `-1`. Also, you never increment `j` either, even when saving your char off. And `string[i] = string2[j];` looks more like a guess than anything else, as it immediately overrides the value you saved on the previous line with *indeterminate* content, since `string2[j]` has never been initialized. Short answer: stop guessing and review your material again.

Comment: So what is in `string2`? And why after `string[i] = tolower(string[i]);` do you immediately overwrite `string[i]`?

Comment: Look into incrementing i by adding `i++;` somewhere in the loop. At least then you'll have a program that terminates on its own instead of endlessly looping.

Comment: do you want like `HAVE` convert to `h.v.` or `hv..` or `hv.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `string` is an *array*, you don't use `&` when passing it to `scanf()`, this gives you a double pointer and is an error.  Any time you find yourself with a 10 clause `if` statement, you're just asking for problems (e.g. easy to get tripped up by typos.) You can simplify this test with `index()` and a string containing all the vowels. It wouldn't hurt to comment as you write your code to indicate which of the requirements each section implements. The `i` variable needs to be incremented every time through the loop, the `j` variable needs to be incremented every time a new character is added to `string2`.  After the `scanf()`, you shouldn't be assigning into `string`, treat it as *readonly*, only assign into `string2`.  And `j-1` shouldn't happen.  Finally, since `string2` isn't intialized, there may be garbage in it and you haven't null terminated it.  Putting it all together:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define VOWELS "AEIOUaeiou"

int main()
{
    char string[100], new_string[100] = { 0 };

    // enter a word
    scanf("%s", string);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        // remove all vowels
        if (index(VOWELS, string[i]) == NULL)
        {
            // make all upper case letters lower case
            new_string[j++] = tolower(string[i]);

            if (isalpha(string[i]))
            {
                new_string[j++] = '.'; // add '.' after every consonant
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", new_string);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming "after every constant" was meant to read "after every consonant", otherwise please clarify what you mean by *constant*.